# How to read a csv file in Spark with multiline text in a cell

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have the following file:

[image]

The 'complaint' column has cases where newlines were created.  When I try to create a Spark df with multiline text in the 'complaint' field, it gets shifted and I end up with:
[image]

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Please use quotes and the multi-line option on the data file.

I will work you thru your test case that does not work.

[image]

Data file without quotes.

[image]

Data file with quotes on text.  Text in both examples is multi-line for the complaint column (fields).

[image]

Both files exist in directory in mounted ADLS Generation 2 storage.  The shell command lists the files in the directory.

The unquoted file returns unwanted rows.  This is our bad test case.

[image]

The quoted file returns the results that you want.  This is our good test case.

[image]

If you hover over the text, you can see a tool tip pop up.  It contains the multi line data in a single cell.

Enclosed is the working code for your use.

```
df2 = spark.read.format("csv") \
  .option("inferSchema", "true") \
  .option("header", "true") \
  .option("sep", ",") \
  .option("multiLine", "true") \
  .option("quote","\"") \
  .load("/mnt/datalake/stack//mline-file-w-quotes.txt")

display(df2)
```